# postgresql Join two table without relation

Tags: sql, postgresql

lets say i have table like this

Table A:

```
column_a
1
2
3
```

Table B:

```
column_b
a
b
c
```

and i want to have result like this:

```
column_a   column_b
1          a
1          b
1          c
2          a
2          b
2          c
3          a
3          b
3          c
```

does it possible to join two table without relation like this using query?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're looking for `cross join`

```
select a.column_a, b.column_b
from a
cross join b
order by a.column_a, b.column_b;
```